# Error installing golang Shopify/sarama Kafka library

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

Getting following error when installing `golang` `github.com/Shopify/sarama` `kafka` library

```
go get github.com/Shopify/sarama

# github.com/Shopify/sarama
go/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/config.go:678:37: undefined: io.Discard
go/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/decompress.go:43:10: undefined: io.ReadAll
go/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/decompress.go:55:10: undefined: io.ReadAll
go/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/sarama.go:89:29: undefined: io.Discard
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ioutil.Discard` and `ioutil.ReadAll` has moved to `io.Discard` and `io.ReadAll` respectively as of Go 1.16,
**You should use Go 1.16 or use an older version of sarama (I think v1.20.1 should work for go1.13)**

Also from [sarama's README](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama#compatibility-and-api-stability):

> Sarama provides a "2 releases + 2 months" compatibility guarantee: we
> support the two latest stable releases of Kafka and Go, and we provide
> a two month grace period for older releases. This means we currently
> officially support Go 1.15 through 1.16, and Kafka 2.7 through 2.8,
> although older releases are still likely to work.